# Why GPU tasks not working except main thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv, decode

I am trying to run a simple OpenCV decoding example with my ip camera by using GPU hardware. Here is my code and working fine:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{                    
    const std::string fname("rtsp://id:pwd@192.168.1.108");
    
    cv::namedWindow("GPU", cv::WINDOW_OPENGL);
    cv::cuda::setGlDevice();
    
    cv::cuda::GpuMat d_frame;
    cv::Ptr<cv::cudacodec::VideoReader> d_reader = cv::cudacodec::createVideoReader(fname);
    
    
    for (;;)
    {
        if (!d_reader->nextFrame(d_frame))
            break;
        
        cv::imshow("GPU", d_frame);
        
        if (cv::waitKey(3) > 0)
            break;
    }

     return 0;

}
```

When I tried to run this code piece as a function via on another thread, I am getting error. Here is the code:

```
void cpp_gpu_thread()
{
    const std::string fname("rtsp://id:pwd@192.168.1.108");
    
    cv::namedWindow("GPU", cv::WINDOW_OPENGL);
    cv::cuda::setGlDevice();
    
    cv::cuda::GpuMat d_frame;
    cv::Ptr<cv::cudacodec::VideoReader> d_reader = cv::cudacodec::createVideoReader(fname);
    
    
    for (;;)
    {
        if (!d_reader->nextFrame(d_frame))
            break;
        
        cv::imshow("GPU", d_frame);
        
        if (cv::waitKey(3) > 0)
            break;
    }
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
                
        thread cpp_gpu(cpp_gpu_thread);
        cpp_gpu.detach();

}
```

## **Error:**

> ....opencv/modules/core/src/cuda/gpu_mat.cu:121: error: (-217:Gpu API
> call) all CUDA-capable devices are busy or unavailable in function
> 'allocate'

I can reach GPU only by main thread, how can I fix this problem.

Comment: This error sometimes comes about when the GL context and CUDA context are created on separate GPUs.  It's also remotely possible that the GPU you are trying to use has its compute mode set to EXCLUSIVE_THREAD

Comment: @RobertCrovella Can you please give me a link for guideline?